# How to load a csc_matrix in an pyspark rdd

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, sparse-matrix, rdd

I have a sparse csc_matrix which I need to load in a RDD. However, RDD **does not** support a direct load of csc_matrix like:

```
sc.parallelize(my_csc_matrix)
```

Is there a way we can convert csc_matrix to a RDD friendly sparse vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can load it into rdd using :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(my_csc_matrix.toarray())
```

but by loading this way, you are again converting your csc_matrix into dense array and then loading. But anyways if you want to load you can load using above code.